# Money transfer api for mobile apps?

Tags: flutter, payment

I'm developing a flutter app, and I've come across different payment solutions such as 
`squareup payments`, `paystack` and `stripe`. However all these systems essentially require you to setup an account with their services, then you can only charge money to those accounts.

What I'm looking to do is enable monetary transfers between users on the app, and simply charge a fee on top. What are the best practises for such a system? So a callable api in the vein of Venmo, or Square Cash that I can call from code when I get the details I need.

Should I create my own backend for this? If so what should I use? (I'm primarily working in golang, but I'm flexible)

Or is there a nifty flutter plugin or API gateway that I can just use directly from the mobile client?

Comment: I think you will need to build your own backend to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various services for doing such a thing,
Usually at my firm we would have our .NET rest server get the payment request from the client, and later charging it with some service that is verified for payments at our country.
Note:

- You will be needing to associate with that service and there will probably be fees.
- Depanding on your country, you most probably MUST NOT store the payment data on your own server unless you have a certificate for doing such a thing (security standerts etc.)
- If this is a private project I would suggest researching about migrating with PayPal since you won't need to handle security and the payment would go through them.

May be helpful: [paypal developers](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/)

Comment: While I thought of paypal, from what I can tell you can only pay paypal or venmo recipients, there's no way to pay to a general account is there?

Comment: Didn't use PayPal yet, but if you research about it youll probably find out 

Comment: How do I know which payment getaway or processor work my country?

Comment: For mobile Money Payments support in Africa for example, there is a list on [MoneyUnify](https://github.com/blessedjasonmwanza/MoneyUnify) you can utilize. [MoneyUnify](https://MoneyUnify.com) also makes it possible to request payments under one API from users.